# jquery click() wont fire with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

I have the following html content.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpi0M.png)

and the following code: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJIYB.png)

The ".menu .icon-fullscreen" cannot be .click(). It does not work. 
I tried already all kind of variations.

Manipulating the css works -> yellow for ex.

[here is the function of the clickable class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLtqo.png)

Any suggestions what may be wrong ?

Comment: Try native DOM: `$(.......)[0].dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true}))`

Comment: Worked! Thank you :)